# Average distance to a pole in a 1D world

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

**My world**

Imagine a 1 dimensional discrete world where there are poles. Let's represent this world by a 1D grid where each slot either contains a pole `I` or does not contains a pole `-`

```
--------I-I---------I----II-------I-------------I--
```

In this world there are `n` slots and `m` poles. We can represent this world either with a vector of length `m` listing the positions of the poles

```
std::vector<unsigned int> polePositions;
```

or with a boolean vector of the length `n`

```
std::vector<bool> isThereAPole;
```

**Statistic of interest and example**

Each slot has an average distance (`averageDistance`) to all poles. For example, below the slot index 2 (zero based counting)

```
---I-I
```

has an average distance to the poles of

> averageDistance = (1 + 3) / 2 = 2

We can then compute this average distance for each slot and average them out to get the average average distance (`averageAverageDistance`). For the above example,

> averageAverageDistance = ((3 + 5) / 2 + (2 + 4)/2 + (1+3)/2 + (0+2)/2 +
>                                   (1 + 1)/2 + (2+0)/2)/6 = 12/6 = 2

**Question**

How to compute this `averageAverageDistance` with high performance?

Typically, I'll have about n=1e6 slots and about m=1e5 poles at each call of the function. `n` will remain the same at every call of the function but `m` (and `polePositions` or `isThereAPole`) will vary among function calls.

**Bad implementation**

Here is a simple implementation using the above small data as example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <math.h>

double getAverageAverageDistance(std::vector<unsigned int> polePositions, int n)
{
    double averageAverageDistance = 0.0;
    for (int slot = 0 ; slot < n ; slot++)
    {
        double averageDistance = 0.0;
        for (auto& polePosition : polePositions)
        {
               averageDistance += fabs(slot - polePosition);
        }
        averageDistance /= polePositions.size();
        averageAverageDistance += averageDistance;
    }
    averageAverageDistance /= n;
    return averageAverageDistance;
}

int main()
{
  std::vector<unsigned int> polePositions;
  polePositions.push_back(3);
  polePositions.push_back(5);
  int n = 6;

  std::cout << "averageAverageDistance = " << getAverageAverageDistance(polePositions, n) << "\n";
}
```

which correctly outputs

```
averageAverageDistance = 2
```

This program has time complexity O(n m). Is there a better solution?

Comment: For each segment between two neighboring poles you can easily compute average distance to pole on this segment and number of elements on the segment.

Comment: That would be easy if I was computing the average distance to the closest pole but I don't think it works if I compute the average average distance to all poles. I might misunderstand what you suggested though. Am I?

Comment: 2 questions: 1) How did you get 11? 2) How 11/6 == 2.2?

Comment: Why is `slot` a double? Same with `averageDistance`. Your positions are ints, vector indices are ints.

Comment: @KillzoneKid Thanks. Small mistake corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a look at the problem from the ground up for 6 slots.

Let's say all the slots are filled. Then, the distances from each slot to
every other slot can be represented in a 6 x 6 matrix as:

```
| 0 1 2 3 4 5 |
| 1 0 1 2 3 4 |
| 2 1 0 1 2 3 |
| 3 2 1 0 1 2 |
| 4 3 2 1 0 1 |
| 5 4 3 2 1 0 |
```

The total distance can be computed by adding all the numbers and dividing
the total by 36.

When a slot is not filled with a pole, that entire column can be removed.
Say, the 2-nd slot is missing. You can remove the entire second column to
get the total sum. Of course, the sum now needs to be divide by 30 and
not 36.

Let's you can represent the sum of all numbers in a column. Call it
`SUM(i)` where `i` is the index of the column.

When the second row is missing, you can represent the total sum as:

```
SUM(0) + SUM(2) + ... + SUM(5)
```

Fortunately, there is a good pattern for the sums and you can represent
`SUM(i)` as function of the total number of slots and `i`.

Let's look at the sums of the columns for `N = 6`.

```
SUM(0) = 5*6/2
```

Let's call the cardinal sum, `CSUM`.

`SUM(1)` is obtained by removing 5 from `CSUM` and then adding 1 to it.

```
SUM(1) = CSUM - (5-1)
```

`SUM(2)` is obtained by removing 5 and 4 from `CSUM` and then adding 2 and 1 to it.

```
SUM(2) = CSUM - (5-2) - (4-1)
=> SUM(2) = CSUM - (5-2) - (5-2)
=> SUM(2) = CSUM - 2*(5-2)
```

`SUM(3)` is obtained by removing 5, 4, and 3 from `CSUM` and then adding 3, 2, and 1 to it.

```
SUM(3) = CSUM - (5-3) - (4-2) - (3-1)
=> SUM(3) = CSUM - (5-3) - (5-3) - (5-3)
=> SUM(3) = CSUM - 3*(5-3)
```

The pattern is that:

```
SUM(i) = CSUM - i*((N-1) - i)
```

In the general case,

```
CSUM = (N-1)*N/2
```

With that knowledge, you can easilty compute the total sum if you know the
indices of the slots where there are poles. It's a `O(M)` operation if there
are `M` poles.

---

A demonstrative program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int SUM(int N, int p)
{
   return (N-1)*N/2 - p*((N-1) - p);
}

int main()
{
   int N = 0;
   int M = 0;

   std::cin >> N;
   std::cin >> M;

   std::vector<int> polePositions;
   for ( int i = 0; i < M; ++i )
   {
      int p;
      std::cin >> p;
      polePositions.push_back(p);
   }

   int s = 0;
   for ( int p : polePositions )
   {
      s += SUM(N, p);
   }

   double average = 1.0*s/(N*polePositions.size());

   std::cout << "Average: " << average << std::endl;
}
```

Given the input

```
6
2
3 5
```

the output is

```
Average: 2
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this can be done in O(m).

The `polePositions` vector has the position of each pole, which is also the distance from the first slot to each pole.  Take the sum of this vector to get the total distance from the first slot to all poles (we'll compute the average later).

As you move thru each slot, this total distance will be reduced by `m`, until you reach a slot with a pole, located at position `p1`.  When we get there, you've added in `(sum - m) + (sum - 2 * m) + ... + (sum - p1 * m)`.  We can easily skip over this distance, and accumulate this into the sum by adding (p1 * ((sum - m) + (sum - p1 * m)) / 2).

Once we pass that first pole, each step to the right will increase the term to add by 1 (as we get farther from p1) while reducing it by m-1, as we get closer to all the other poles.  So you'd repeat the previous step, adding (sum - (m - 2)) for each slot.

Continue until you've added in terms for each pole.  Eventually you'll reach the middle, and the term will increase instead of decrease.

For the last term, add in the sum for all the slots to the right of the last pole.  Then divide the whole sum by `n`.

(That's the undebugged algorithm.)